# Query posts that have at least 3 of the tags of the current post

Tags: tags

I'm trying to find a way to query posts on that have at least X tags in common with the current post. [This example](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/103078/posts-with-at-least-3-tags-of-a-list-of-tags) is close but I don't want to have to nominate which tags.

```
//List of tag slugs
$tags = array('SOMEHOW INCLUDE ALL TAGS');

$args = array(
    'tag_slug__in' => $tags
    //Add other arguments here
);

// This query contains posts with at least one matching tag
$tagged_posts = new WP_Query($args);

echo '<ul>';
while ( $tagged_posts->have_posts() ) : $tagged_posts->the_post();
   // Check each single post for up to 3 matching tags and output <li>
   $tag_count = 0;
   $tag_min_match = 2;
   foreach ( $tags as $tag ) {
      if ( has_tag( $tag ) && $tag_count < $tag_min_match ) {
         $tag_count ++;
      }
   }
   if ($tag_count == $tag_min_match) {
      //Echo list style here
      echo '<li><a href="'. get_permalink() .'" title="'. get_the_title() .'">'. get_the_title() .'</a></li>';
   }
endwhile;
wp_reset_query();
echo '</ul>';
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: I'm assuming I have at least 3 tags in common

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
<?php
//List of tag slugs
$tags = array();

$posttags = get_the_tags();
if ($posttags) {
  foreach($posttags as $tag) {
    $tags[] = $tag->term_id; 
  }
}

$args = array(
    'tag__in' => $tags
    //Add other arguments here
);

// This query contains posts with at least one matching tag
$tagged_posts = new WP_Query($args);

echo '<ul>';
while ( $tagged_posts->have_posts() ) : $tagged_posts->the_post();
   // Check each single post for up to 3 matching tags and output <li>
   $tag_count = 0;
   $tag_min_match = 2;
   foreach ( $tags as $tag ) {
      if ( has_tag( $tag ) && $tag_count < $tag_min_match ) {
         $tag_count ++;
      }
   }
   if ($tag_count >= $tag_min_match) {
      //Echo list style here
      echo '<li><a href="'. get_permalink() .'" title="'. get_the_title() .'">'. get_the_title() .'</a></li>';
   }
endwhile;
wp_reset_query();
echo '</ul>';
```

The code will fetch all the tags associated with the current post, search other posts with similar tags and return post if 2 or more tags are matched.

Hope this helps.

Comment: did the code work?

Comment: If I make the tag threshold to '1' then it shows some posts, but if I make the threshold '2' is shows no posts.

Comment: This is working fine on my side. Please make sure that you have 2 posts with 2 or more similar tags in the same post type.

Comment: Yes I definitely have 2 posts with 2 or more similar tags in the same post type

Comment: https://pastebin.com/hJkDqMej is my theme file. It starts on line 252

Comment: I've also added my cpt support `$args = array(
    'tag__in' => $tags,
 'post_type' => 'teacher'
    //Add other arguments here
);`

Comment: Sorry I've found a problem with my tags which is probably accounting for it not working.

Comment: cool. Glad I could help.

Comment: It appears it is not working, I've fixed up my tags.

Comment: I have many custom posts with at least 4 tags in common but they are not displaying

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70502/discussion-between-pete-and-sid).